# Adobe Native Extensions - Voice Recognition

Tags: android, apache-flex

People, dear Android-Coders,

currently I am coding a android mobile app in Flex with the Flash Builder. I am tring to get the Voice Recognition of the Android Platform working but it seems to be complicated.

I managed to write a Native Extension that at least displays the Android style voice recognition that asks for speech input. I found out that for the android system the speech input dialog represents an activity where you can wait for the activity's response and overwrite the onActivityResult function.

And there is the problem. Since I have to call the Activity "Voice Recognition" in the FREContext the response of the Voice Recognition Activity gets lost.

Please see the java code attached. I hope that someone's able to help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;


import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;
import com.adobe.fre.FREObject;

public class VoiceRecognitionStart extends Activity implements FREFunction {
          private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
          private VoiceRecognitionContext vrc = null;
          private Activity a;
          @Override
          public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] passedArgs) {
                    vrc = (VoiceRecognitionContext) context;
                    a = VoiceRecognitionStart.this;



                    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Bitte sprechen...");
        intent.setClass(VoiceRecognitionStart.this, VoiceRecognitionResult.class);
        a.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

  return null;
          }
          protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
                    System.out.println("ON ACTIVITY " + resultCode);
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
            vrc.matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        }
       System.out.println("vrc.matches " + vrc.matches);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also like to have a look at this version which works totally in background with no activity overlaying the Air app: http://myappsnippet.com/google-speech-api-air-native-extension/